# Pyspark UDF AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a udf function:

```
@staticmethod
@F.udf("array<int>")
def create_users_array(val):
    """ Takes column of ints, returns column of arrays containing ints. """ 
    return [val for _ in range(val)]
```

I call it like so:

```
df.withColumn("myArray", create_users_array(df["myNumber"]))
```

I pass it a dataframe column of integers, and it returns an array of that integer.

E.g. 
`4 --> [4,4,4,4]`

It was working until we upgraded from Python 2.7, and upgraded our EMR version (which I believe uses Pyspark 2.3)

Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  It looks like you're at least mixing different `DataFrames` (`df_agg` and `df`) and using classes requires a lot of caution. And `udf` you posted works fine in isolation.

Comment: ah sorry, copied code over incorrectly (changed `df_agg` to `df`)

Comment: It is still not reproducible with this code.

Comment: @user9613318 well, you'd have to set up an EMR cluster with the same configuration as mine, so it's not easily "reproducible". I fixed it though; answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this had something to do with the improvements made to UDFs in the newer version (or rather, deprecation of old syntax). Changing the udf decorator worked for me. `@F.udf("array<int>")` --> `@F.udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()))`